# Pass data to component shown using $mdDialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-components, mddialog

I am using angular 1.6.2 and angular-material 1.1.4. Here is the component that I use for $mdDialog:

```
class CommentReplySettingsController {
  /** @ngInject */
  constructor($mdDialog, $log) {
    this.$mdDialog = $mdDialog;
    $log.log(this.settingType);
  }

  hideDialog() {
    this.$mdDialog.hide();
  }

  cancelDialog() {
    this.$mdDialog.cancel();
  }
}

export const commentReplySettings = {
  template: require('./comment-reply-settings.html'),
  bindings: {
    settingType: '<'
  },
  controller: CommentReplySettingsController
};
```

The above is converted into a component like this:

```
import angular from 'angular';

import {commentReplySettings} from './comment-reply-settings';

export const commentReplySettingsModule = 'commentReplySettings';

angular
  .module(commentReplySettingsModule, [])
  .component('app.user.commentReplySettings', commentReplySettings);
```

And here another component's controller function in which I am using the above component inside $mdDialog:

```
  showCommentReplySettingDialog(ev) {
    this.settingType = 'global';
    this.$mdDialog.show({
      template: '<app.user.comment-reply-settings class="md-dialog-container" setting-type="$ctrl.settingType"></app.user.comment-reply-settings>',
      parent: angular.element(this.$document.body),
      autoWrap: false,
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      fullscreen: true
    });
  }
```

The problem is that **this.settingType** inside **CommentReplySettingsController** is always undefined. How to get this to work?

**Edit:** If I use **`settingType: '@'`** in **CommentReplySettingsController** and do **`setting-type="global"`** in **showCommentReplySettingDialog** function above, the value in settingType binding is set correctly. Seems like **$ctrl** is getting undefined when using inside template. Any reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `$ctrl` is referenced inside `$scope`, hence, when I use `scope: this.$scope`, it works perfectly fine:

```
const _this = this;
this.settingType = 'global';
this.$mdDialog.show({
  template: '<app.user.comment-reply-settings class="md-dialog-container" setting-type="$ctrl.settingType"></app.user.comment-reply-settings>',
  parent: angular.element(this.$document.body),
  autoWrap: false,
  scope: _this.$scope,
  targetEvent: ev,
  clickOutsideToClose: true,
  fullscreen: true
});
```

But still the need to pass `$scope` seems a little absurd. Wish if there is any other solution without `$scope`.